# Matrix of geospatial distance between each actor in a data frame?

Tags: r, matrix, transformation, geosphere

Good evening,
I am trying to calculate the distance from each row in a data frame to the other rows. My data looks like this:

```
gps <- data.frame(company = c("Jonas","Felix","Maria","Anna"),
           longitude = c(42.33606636507468, 37.66663067079797, 
                     35.68203407502485, 49.424044748467686),
           latitude = c(-87.83678044061604, -122.39787657270155, 
                     139.6860258167475, 8.674680432095006))
```

The output should resemble a 4*4 matrix listing the distance between each person, something like this (these numbers are made up, of course):

```
result <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
result <- cbind(c(0,1,5,6),c(1,0,3,7),c(5,3,0,7),c(6,7,7,0))
```

So far I have tried to use the geosphere package:

```
gps_mat <- distm(gps[,c('longitude','latitude')], gps[,c('longitude','latitude')], fun=distVincentyEllipsoid)
```

However, I get the error "Error in .pointsToMatrix(x) : latitude < -90" and am unsure how to proceed. I already tried reducing the digits of my gps coordinates as was proposed in some other questions, but still get the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the sf-package and think that this worked:

```
library(sf)

gps_sf <- st_as_sf(gps,
  agr = NA_agr_,
  coords = c("longitude", "latitude"),
  remove = TRUE,
  na.fail = TRUE,
  sf_column_name = NULL
)

gps_matrix <- st_distance(gps_sf)
```

If there is a more elegant way or an explanation for the error produced by my geosphere-approach, I am interested to hear it.